# How to iterate through Map by values and if the values are same sort them by key?

Tags: java

I have teams and their points in a HashMap.I am able to sort them by their values.

```
Map<String, Integer> sortedMap = Points.entrySet().stream()
            .sorted(Collections.reverseOrder(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue, (e1, e2) -> e1, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Now i would like to iterate over the sortedMap and print the keys in order and if there are matching values, then sort the keys having the same values and then print the result.

Comment: You can always sort by value and then by key, just by creating a combined comparator that does all that at once, instead of doing two phases.  That's pretty straightforward with the Comparator API.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can chain comparators using [`thenComparing`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#thenComparing-java.util.Comparator-):

```
Map<String, Integer> sortedMap = Points.entrySet().stream()
        .sorted(Collections
                .reverseOrder(
                        Map.Entry.<String, Integer>comparingByValue())
                .thenComparing(Map.Entry.comparingByKey()))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue,
                (e1, e2) -> e1, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

This will change your existing single comparison to a two-level comparison. When two elements are considered equal by the first comparator, the second one is used to determine the order.

Note that Java 8 introduced a [`reversed`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#reversed--) method for comparators which is slighty less verbose than `Collections.reverseOrder`:

```
Map<String, Integer> sortedMap = in.entrySet().stream()
        .sorted(Map.Entry.<String, Integer>comparingByValue().reversed()
                .thenComparing(Map.Entry.comparingByKey()))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue,
                (e1, e2) -> e1, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Comment: For clarity, the change here is changing from a single comparison to a two-level comparison: Collections.reverseOrder(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()) → `Collections.reverseOrder(Map.Entry.<String, Integer>comparingByValue()).thenComparing(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())`.

Comment: Certainly. Glad to help.

Comment: Hi, just a comment about style... I'd use `Map.Entry.<String, Integer>comparingByValue().reversed()...` instead of the version with `Collections.reverseOrder(...)`

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner Good point. I sticked to what the OP wrote, but that's certainly more Java 8 style.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Collections.sort( list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>()
        {
            public int compare( Map.Entry<String, Integer> o1, Map.Entry<String, Integer> o2 )
            {
int cmp=o1.getValue().compareTo( o2.getValue());
              if(cmp ==0)
                return (o1.getKey().compareTo( o2.getKey() );//Ascending order
               else{
                  return cmp;
            }
        } );
```

Comment: While this is logically correct, it seems clunky to use such verbose code, considering the original code is using Java 8 method references and Comparators.

Answer (score 0):

Let's break this into different sections, tackling one task at  a time:

**Task Number One: Iteration over the map**

According to the Map API, you can get a set of keys from the map by calling `keySet()`.

```
for (String s : sortedMap.keySet()) {
    System.out.println(s + ": " + sortedMap.get(s));
}
```

This prints out all of the key-value pairs in the map.

**Task Number Two: Check for Matching Values and Sort**

We will use a `List` of strings that have the same value.  By reordering our map like this, we can then use the length of the list to determine if the value is shared by multiple strings.

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> reveresed = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, List<String>>();
for (String s : sortedMap.keySet()) {
    if (reversed.contains(sortedMap.get(s)) {
        reversed.get(sortedMap.get(s)).add(s);
    }
    else
    {
        List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
        values.add(s);
        reversed.put(sortedMap.get(s), values);
    }
}
```

Using this, to query if there are duplicates, we can check this:

```
if (reversed.get(value) != null && reversed.get(value).size() >= 2) {
    // Value is repeated
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, here's a way to do it using Java 8 features, but without streams:

```
List<Entry<String, Integer>> entries = new ArrayList<>(points.entrySet());
entries.sort(Entry.<String, Integer>comparingByValue().reversed()
    .thenComparing(Entry.comparingByKey()));
Map<String, Integer> sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap<>(points.size());
entries.forEach(e -> sortedMap.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue()));
```